# Issue with numpy array append

Tags: numpy

```
sorted_on_conf=np.argsort(-temp_softmax_pred)[:10]
top10_x = np.empty( (0, 32, 32, 3) )
top10_y=np.empty((0,10))
for index in sorted_on_conf:  
    top10_x = np.append( top10_x, dss_x[index], axis=0 )
```

dss_x dimensionsare (10000,32,32,3), index is nothing but index of items in dss_x. I am getting following error.

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 4 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 3 dimension(s)

Please help me with this.

Comment: Don't do this. Use list append if you must iterate.  But what is shape of `dss_x[0]`?

Comment: Can't you just do `dss_x[sorted_indices]`? Why the loop?